# How to separate list by type in angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I started working with angular recently and I'm trying to divide a list in two by their type and show it in two separated fields. My question is: can I do it by doing a for loop in the .ts file or there is an easier way?

HTML file:

```
      <div class="ml-xs mr-xs my-flex-column">
        <p>Interests:</p>
        <ul style="list-style-type:disc;" *ngFor="let interests of item.profileInterest">
          <li> {{ interests.name }} </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="ml-xs mr-xs my-flex-column">
        <p>Behaviors:</p>
        <ul style="list-style-type:disc;" *ngFor="let behaviors of item.profileInterest">
          <li> {{ behaviors.name }} </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

.ts file:

```
public getCustomerProfile() {
    this.blockUI.start("Loading");
    this._service.getCustomerProfile(this.id)
      .subscribe(
        (data: RequestCustomerProfile[]) => {
          if (data.length && data.length > 0) {
            this.entityProfile = data;
          } else {
            this.entityProfile = [];
          }
          this.blockUI.stop();
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error)
          this.blockUI.stop();
        }
      );
  }
```

Comment: What are you asking? What is it you are actually trying to do and why do you want to do that thing another way? What does the code have to do with the question? How are the template code and the typescript code related (there is no direct relation at all in the code you have provided)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to treat the HTML file directly, just deal with it and check the "li" tag:

```
<div class="ml-xs mr-xs my-flex-column">
<p>Interest:</p>
<ul *ngFor="let interests of item.profileInterest">
    <li *ngIf="interests.type == 'Interest'"> {{ interests.name }} </li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="ml-xs mr-xs my-flex-column">
<p>Behavior:</p>
<ul *ngFor="let behaviors of item.profileInterest">
    <li *ngIf="behaviors.type == 'Behavior'"> {{ behaviors.name }} </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To do it in the .ts file you could do this:

```
get interests() {
  return item.profileInterests.filter(interest => interest.type === 'Interest');
}


get behaviours() {
  return item.profileInterests.filter(interest => interest.type === 'Behaviour');
}
```

(note that I have no idea of the structure of item.profileInterests, this is just a guess)

Then in the html you can use them like this:

```
  <div class="ml-xs mr-xs my-flex-column">
    <p>Interests:</p>
    <ul style="list-style-type:disc;" *ngFor="let interest of interests">
      <li> {{ interest.name }} </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="ml-xs mr-xs my-flex-column">
    <p>Behaviors:</p>
    <ul style="list-style-type:disc;" *ngFor="let behavior of behaviors">
      <li> {{ behavior.name }} </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

This way when you want behaviours and interests elsewhere you can just use those getter variables (you don't need to call them with parentheses!).